Does this property hold for complex matrices?
Many matrix options,such as matrix–matrix multiplication and LU factorization, share the property that the number of additions/subtractions is equal to the number of multiplications. Does this property hold for complex matrices, assuming complex arithmetic has to be implemented using real arithmetic? In my view,(a+bi)(c+di)=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i,it requires 4 real multiplications and 2 real additions.So this property doesn't hold for complex matrices.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In the elementary algorithm for matrix product, aren't the number of sums $n^2(n-1)$ and the number of products $n^3$?

It seems to me that you answered your own question!
As you point out: 1 complex multiplication corresponds to 2 real additions and 4 real multiplications. Also a complex addition corresponds to 2 real additions and no real complifactions.
So if we have an operation that requires $a$ additions and $m$ multiplications in the field the matrix is defined over, it will have $a$ real additions and $m$ real multiplications if all entries are real and $2a + 2m$ real additions and $4m$ real multiplications if all entries are complex.
Things get more complicated if some entries are real and some are complex.
This talks about the general case. In the special case where $a = m = k$ for some $k$ we have $2a + 2m = 4k$ and $4m = 4k$ as well, so the property is preserved!
However as Sassastelli points out, $a = m$ might be rarer than you think. Perhaps the questions is about the more general phenomenon where $a$ and $m$ have the same growth rate as the size of the matrices growth to infinity, i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} m(n)/a(n) = 1$? It seems that from the above it follows that that weaker property is also preserved when passing from all real to all complex matrices and counting real operations.
